# RRAS VPN - Clients don't receive DNS suffix

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras

I've setup a VPN connection using RRAS on Windows Server 2008 and clients are able to connect through the firewall.

However, RRAS is not assigning a DNS suffix to the clients when they connect.

I know how to set the client to automatically add the DNS suffix on the client side (through the IPv4 Advanced properties) but I'd like to configure things on the server side to automatically set this.

We're using a static address pool which may be relevant information.

Can somebody please tell me where I would set this up?

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=232703.

Comment: This is what I ended up using to get things working. If you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll award the check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joeqwerty answered this as a comment and never moved it to the answer field so I'm answering it instead.

The answer resides in this MS article:

[How to Use DHCP to Provide Routing and Remote Access Clients with Additional DHCP Options](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=232703)

Comment: The link dead. Did anybody find a new version if this article?